# Windows Forms Constructor is called multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a simple windows forms application, this form creates multiple new objects upon initialization which in some circumstances (when there are errors) present the user with a messagebox dialog with some text.

My problem is that in the event of an error the message dialog is presented multiple times. When checking why this happens I have found that the constructor of the windows forms application was being called multiple times, four to be exact. Somehow I don't think that this is normal behavior...

My application consists of a `Main()` inside of a MainWindow.cs file;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Setup();
    }

    private void Setup()
    {
        stuff = new Stuff(this);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        Application.Run(new MainWindow());
    }
```

Inside the constructor of `Stuff` is where the `MessageDialog` is being displayed.

Adding a breakpoint in the constructor of `MainWindow()` I can see that it is being called multiple times.

Can someone enlighten me to why this is and if there is anything that I can do to prevent it from happening?

I have tried to suppress the dialog box through the use of a `boolean` variable but since the object is being re-created I can not do this (and shouldn't have to anyways...)

Comment: No, constructor isn't called multiple times (in the code you posted). In case your breakpoint is hitted multiple times...an useful tip may be to inspect the full stack trace...

Comment: Threading maybe? or the Application.Run(new MainWindow()) should it not call another Form instead of itself?

Comment: @Edper Threading shouldn't be an issue since I have not created any new thread to deal with that window. The Application.Run is not calling on itself since it is called inside of the static method Main.

Comment: Could you show your code on your Stuff class (form?) or have you tried to put a break point also in your Stuff class? By the way is MainWindow.cs a form?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the constructor in the debugger, then inspect the stack to see what's calling it.

Comment: @Edper MainWindow.cs is a form. Even if I do not have the Stuff initialisation there it will still jump inot MainWindow() multiple times. I have tried having breakpoints in MainWindow(), Setup() and Stuff(); all break 4 times.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It is called from `Forms.MainWindow.Main()` Line 166, every time.

Comment: @Sander you should show us the code in the `Stuff()` method, or you may want to try commenting out the line `Setup();` and see if there is any difference?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out  Application.Run(new MainWindow()) or SetUp() (this is only a hunch) or you could not do that because this (MainWindow.cs) is the entry point for your program? And I would echo as with others comment to Debug and Trace if possible before even the Form is called.

Comment: @KingKing commenting out Stuff() makes no difference, the problem lies in constructor of the form being called multiple times.

Comment: @Sander that's strange, I think you must have some code which is not shown, your problem is in that code.

Answer (score 0):

you should not put a messagebox in the constructor. The caller should handle any exception an he should show the messagebox

```
private void Caller()
{
    try
    {
        frmStuff frm = new frmStuff();
        frm.Show();
    }
    catch
    {
        //show your messagebox here
    }
}
```

Comment: The Messagebox is not shown every time the object is being created, it is only to present errors to the user (as stated in my question).

Comment: Also, the "Caller" is a constructor

Comment: In your case the caller is `Setup()` I know the messagebox isn't always shown. Depending if this is causing exception or not, if not you could move your object initialisation in the form load